# Stripe transactions that make up a payout for a connect account

Tags: php, laravel, api, stripe-payments

I am trying to get a list of all the transactions that make up a payout for a connect account from stripe with their API.

I am trying to do this so that I can reconcile sales less refunds and fees per day against a payout.

I am able to list the payouts per connect account but am really struggling to get the transactions per payout.  I have tried listing the balance transactions and specifying the payout but Stripe support tell me that won't work for a connect account only for the platform account and that I need to get the reports from the web which is useless for me having to reconcile many connect accounts.

my desired output is per payout:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>payout arrival date</td>
        <td>payout amount</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>date</td>
        <td>sales value for the day less refunds and fees</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>date</td>
        <td>sales value for the day less refunds and fees</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and both the sales_values will sum to the payout_amount.

I would love any advice I have been struggling on and off with stripe support for a few days on this one.

I am happy to store all this data in a database and do a SQL join, if it comes to that, if thats the correct approach, how do I relate the data?

Laravel 5.8, with the stripe SDK

Thanks

Cam

Comment: "Stripe support tell me that won't work for a connect account only for the platform account" Hmm, that's definitely not true unfortunately. It's simply https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/list#balance_transaction_list-payout + https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication (to make the request on behalf of each connected account), that's it really.

Comment: Thanks for your help       Heres the code in case someone else needs this in the future:


`$a = \Stripe\BalanceTransaction::all(
                `['limit' => 100],
                `['payout' => 'po_id'],
                `['stripe_account' => 'acct_id']
                `);